# ListView Background

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView and it has a Header and Footer. Their layout in CardView. And Content list in which one must be background. Here is a picture which can be clearly seen: I now this is how it turns out:

[image]

And how to do:

[image]

I did so, ScrollView> first container>listView in second container > third container. But, unfortunately, at the bottom of the container 2 it was a huge empty space!

Is it possible to implement a so-in ListView? if so how, if not then how to implement?

UPDATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Details.Book.BookDetails"
android:background="@color/fragment_bg">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/view5" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout16">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_layout"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="@string/buy_det_pass_txt"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_fullname"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_gender"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvGender"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_ticknumber"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTickNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_issdate"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvIssDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <kz.tem_tour.Primer.MainActivity.NonScrollListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout16" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listView">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_layout"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/buy_det_cost_txt"
                    android:id="@+id/tvFromTo"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rightPadding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout9"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_fare"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvFare"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_taxes"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTaxes"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_service_fees"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvFees"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_total_price"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTotPrice"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textMargin" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/buy_det_form_of_pay"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainSmallSize" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Medium Text"
                        android:id="@+id/tvPayment"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/mainGreyColor"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mainMiddleSize" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Only one solution is (propably) put all items (except header and footer) into one item in ListView and set background for them.

Comment: do not quite understand, can be more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution for that.. not healthy one but it should work for you.

Rather then adding header and footer wrap all three layout inside `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView ... >

    <CardView ... /> <!-- this will be header -->

    <CardView ...>

        <yourpackagename.NonScrollListView ... /> <!-- non scrollable listview -->

    </CardView>

    <CardView ... /> <!-- this will footer -->

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the class for **NonScrollListView**

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Comment: such a component is not present

Comment: can you elaborate it more?

Comment: does not start app... Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #200: Error inflating class kz.tem_tour.Primer.MainActivity.NonScrollListView

Comment: you need to add NonScrollListView with package name i.e `<yourpackagename.NonScrollListView ...>`

Comment: That's exactly what I did

Comment: i think you have wrote that class inside MainActivity. instead you have to make it separate class. it will work as on of the widget. so under `kz.tem_tour` (which is I guess your package) make separate class.

Comment: It helped, thank you. but now the problem is when you start to automatically focus on the listview

Comment: in your Java code disable focuse of your listview... i.e `listview.setFocusable(false);`.

Answer (score 0):

Add listview in CardView and above that cardview add header in different card view and same add footer in cardview under ListView cardview. And add whole layout is scrollview. Calculate height of listview at runtime and add height to listview. Your custom look is ready.

public static void setTotalHeightofListView(ListView listView) {

```
ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

int totalHeight = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

    mView.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
    Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

}

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight
        + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.requestLayout();
```

}